# How to stop JavaScript alert from refreshing page?

Tags: javascript, php, html, mysql, dropzone.js

I am teaching myself, so I apologize in advance if this is a 'newbie' question, but I have searched the internet and cannot find a solution.

So I've created a HTML form, and in that form I have added a Dropzone.js where people upload a file. When finished they click a button which saves it into a MySQL form, that all works great. The issue is when people click the button before the file finishes uploading. To counteract this issue, I've created an 'If Statement' that checks if the uploaded file exists. If it hasn't uploaded, then a JavaScript alert is triggered, which all works, but it refreshes the page, which erases all the imputed data.

```
// This is when the button is clicked
if(isset($_POST['Upload'])){
    if (file_exists(blah blah) {

        //All my MySQL stuff is in here



    //If it isn't uploaded 
    } else {
        echo '<script language="javascript">';
        echo 'alert("Please upload at least one file")';
        echo 'return false';
        echo '</script>';
    }}
```

Despite the 'return false'; it still resets the page?

Any help would be appreciated, thanks!

Comment: You're not adding semicolons on your javascript. Not sure if that's the reason tho

Comment: @PhiterFernandes, I fixed that up, it wasn't the reason. But thanks anyway.

Answer (score -1):

Can you show me the all code. You can do it with lots of methods i do it with validation. you can set a variable which increase on file upload. if variable value zero then return false form will not submit.

Php does not support like this echo 'return false'. you have to use JavaScript validation for this purpose.

Comment: i just implement the same thing with laravel.

Comment: $('#submit-btn').on('submit',  function(e) {
return false;
});

Comment: Sure, unfortunately it was too long for a comment, but I pasted in into here: https://jsfiddle.net/wsw9svnm/4/

Comment: Are you using dropzone.js for uploading the images?

Comment: Yes, but also files in the format .3mf, .stl, .fbx, .dae, .stp, .obj. And only once the file is fully uploaded will the file exist function notice that it is there.

Comment: as i know your problem you should use the java script/ jquery  for validation for this process if file there with JavaScript check then submit the form otherwise it will not submitted.